# Why does Samba want the root password when joining an ADS domain?

Tags: linux-networking, samba4

Best practice on *NIX servers is to leave the root password unset and then use `sudo`. However, when one uses Samba's `net join` command, even through `sudo`, it still asks for the root password. Why? Doesn't it have all the local privileges it needs?

```
username@host:~$ sudo net join
[sudo] password for username:
Enter root's password:
```

Comment: OK. I have a hunch, based on other `net` commands, that since I didn't specify an AD user with `-U`, it's just going to try and use the AD username, "root". I don't get this same prompt when I specify `-U`. This isn't very intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: Instead of `-U username`, you might also be able to use `-P` (`--machine-pass`) to skip the password prompt. That works for me to run various `net` commands on the AD server itself when I'm logged in as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is who you are running the command as, you should use:
-U a user that can join a computer to the domain, this is typically 'Administrator'

You also do not need local privileges, you need domain privileges.

Comment: Makes sense now. It didn't when I asked the question. :)